# Why does Laravel mix create a new folder with mix-manifest.json after npm run dev command and gives the error 500

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8, laravel-mix

> I hope you are doing well

I changed public folder to public_html folder. After executing this command { npm run dev } A new public folder is created and the mix-manifest.json file is placed in it and it the error 500 is returned.

I tried these steps.

1. ./app/AppServiceProvider.php
   add this code

   ```
   public function register()
   {
   $this->app->bind(
       \Auth0\Login\Contract\Auth0UserRepository::class,
       \Auth0\Login\Repository\Auth0UserRepository::class
   );

   $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
       return base_path().'/public_html';
     });

   }
   ```
2. ./config/filesystems.php change public to public_html

   ```
    'public' => ['driver' => 'local','root' =>
     storage_path('app/public_html'),'url' =>
     env('APP_URL').'/storage','visibility' => 'public',],
   ```
3. ./webpack.mix.js change public to public_html

   ```
    mix.config.publicPath='public_html';
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public_html/js')
          .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public_html/css');
   ```
4. index.php add this code

   ```
   $app->bind('path.public', function() { return __DIR__; });
   ```
5. ./bootstrap/app.php add this code

   ```
   $app->bind('path.public', function() { return base_path().'/public_html'; });
   ```

[Created public folder picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBBxB.png)

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I appreciate your help.